# Autoit scheduled task

Tags: autoit, minecraft

I am trying to set up a program that will run a function whenever the time of the host computer reaches a certain hour or minute. It seems like I will need something to always check the time, but not block anything. The function Say() is a sample that shows that at a certain point in time, a function will be triggered. Backup() is a function I want to back up a folder and change name to the date it was made. I don't know how I would go about to make the time working. Any suggestions?

```
#include <ComboConstants.au3>
#include <StaticConstants.au3>
#include <GUIConstantsEx.au3>
#include <WindowsConstants.au3>
#include <Misc.au3>
#include <EditConstants.au3>
#include <WindowsConstants.au3>
#include <Date.au3>

Global $hwnd, $pid, $Server, $time, $min, $sec, $hour, $Counter, $s_Source, $s_Destination, $i_Flag
MsgBox(0, "Test", Time())
Start()
While 1
If $Server = "Running" Then
    If ProcessWaitClose($pid) = 1 Then Exit
EndIf
If $time = "20:15:00" Then Say()
WEnd

Func Start()
If @error Then
    Sleep(1)
Else
    Run('java -jar -Xmx1024M "C:\Users\Kristian\Desktop\Minecraft Server\minecraft_server.jar"', "C:\Users\Kristian\Desktop\Minecraft Server\", @SW_SHOW)
    Sleep(1000)
    WinSetTitle("C:\Windows\system32\java.exe", "", "MCS")
    WinSetTitle("C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\java.exe", "", "MCS")
    Global $hwnd = WinGetHandle("MCS")
    Global $pid = WinGetProcess("MCS")
    Sleep(1000)
    Global $Server = "Running"
    Sleep(10000)
EndIf
EndFunc   ;==>Start

Func Say()
WinActivate($hwnd)
Sleep(1000)
ControlSend("MCS", "", $hwnd, 'say Hello')
Sleep(1000)
ControlSend("MCS", "", $hwnd, '{ENTER}')
Sleep(1000)
EndFunc   ;==>Say


Func Backup()
$Counter += 1
DirCreate("C:\ServerBackups")
FileCopy("C:\Users\Kristian\Desktop\Minecraft Server\world\*.*", "C:\ServerBackups\")
_FileRename_($s_Source, $s_Destination, $i_Flag = $time)
EndFunc   ;==>Backup

Func _FileRename_($s_Source, $s_Destination, $i_Flag = $time)
Local $i
$i = FileMove($s_Source, $s_Destination, $i_Flag)
Return $i
EndFunc   ;==>_FileRename_

Func Time()
$min = @MIN
$sec = @SEC
$hour = @HOUR
$time = $hour & ":" & $min & ":" & $sec
Return $time
EndFunc   ;==>Time
```

What I made from the suggestions:

```
Global $Server, $pid, $time, $save = 0
$Read = RegRead("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\KnarCraft", "Version")
$Path1 = @TempDir & "\versions.json"
If Not InetGet("https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/versions/versions.json", $Path1, 1, 0) = 0 Then $FF = FileOpen($Path1)
$RF = FileReadLine($FF, 3)
If $Read = $RF And FileExists("E:\Spill\Alle spill\Minecraft\Tools\YAMS\servers\7\minecraft_server.jar") Then
Else
    $ver1 = StringReplace($RF, '    "snapshot": "', "")
    $ver = StringReplace($ver1, '",', "")
    If InetGet('https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/versions/' & $ver & "/minecraft_server." & $ver & ".jar", "E:\Spill\Alle spill\Minecraft\Tools\YAMS\servers\7\minecraft_server.jar", 1, 0) = 1 Then RegWrite("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\KnarCraft", "Version", "REG_SZ", $RF)
EndIf
FileDelete($Path1)
$2 = Run('java -jar -Xmx3072M "E:\Spill\Alle spill\Minecraft\Tools\YAMS\servers\7\minecraft_server.jar"', "E:\Spill\Alle spill\Minecraft\Tools\YAMS\servers\7\", @SW_HIDE)
If Not ProcessWait($2) = 0 Then WinSetTitle("C:\Windows\system32\java.exe", "", "MCS")
Global $hwnd = WinGetHandle("MCS"), $pid = WinGetProcess("MCS"), $Server = "Running"
While 1
    AdlibRegister("Checktime", 1000)
    If $Server = "Running" And ProcessWaitClose($pid) = 1 Then Exit
WEnd
Func Checktime()
    If @MIN = 00 Or @MIN = 10 Or @MIN = 20 Or @MIN = 30 Or @MIN = 40 Or @MIN = 50 And @SEC = 00 Then ControlSend("MCS", "", $hwnd, 'say Report bugs and errors here: http://knar.world-servers.com/f6-problems-and-suggestions' & '{ENTER}')
    If @MIN = 05 Or @MIN = 15 Or @MIN = 25 Or @MIN = 35 Or @MIN = 45 Or @MIN = 55 And @SEC = 00 Then ControlSend("MCS", "", $hwnd, 'say Warning: Server may be unstable' & '{ENTER}')
    If @MIN = 37 And @SEC = 00 Then
        If ControlSend("MCS", "", $hwnd, "say Commencing Backup" & '{ENTER}') = 1 Then RunWait(@ComSpec & ' /c xcopy /e /c /h /i /v /r /y /q "' & "E:\Spill\Alle spill\Minecraft\Tools\YAMS\servers\7\world" & '" "' & "E:\Spill\Alle spill\Minecraft\Tools\YAMS\servers\7\backup\" & @MDAY & "-" & @MON & "-" & @YEAR & "-" & @HOUR & "-" & @MIN & "H" & "\world" & '"')
    EndIf
    If @HOUR = 20 And @MIN = 15 Then
        If ControlSend("MCS", "", $hwnd, "say Commencing Backup" & '{ENTER}') = 1 Then RunWait(@ComSpec & ' /c xcopy /e /c /h /i /v /r /y /q "' & "E:\Spill\Alle spill\Minecraft\Tools\YAMS\servers\7\world" & '" "' & "E:\Spill\Alle spill\Minecraft\Tools\YAMS\servers\7\backup\" & @MDAY & "-" & @MON & "-" & @YEAR & "-" & @HOUR & "-" & @MIN & "D" & "\world" & '"')
    EndIf
    If @HOUR = 00 And @MIN = 00 Then
        If ControlSend("MCS", "", $hwnd, "say Restarting Server" & '{ENTER}' & "stop" & '{ENTER}') = 1 Then Shutdown(2)
    EndIf
    If @MIN = 00 Or @MIN = 05 Or @MIN = 10 Or @MIN = 15 Or @MIN = 20 Or @MIN = 25 Or @MIN = 30 Or @MIN = 35 Or @MIN = 40 Or @MIN = 45 Or @MIN = 50 Or @MIN = 55 And @SEC = 07 Then ControlSend("MCS", "", $hwnd, 'say Saving World' & '{ENTER}' & 'save-all' & '{ENTER}')
EndFunc   ;==>Checktime
```

Comment: Check out the AdLibRegister function. This will give you the ability to set a specific time interval to run your programs at. http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/AdlibRegister.htm

Comment: Also check out the _NowTime() function. http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_NowTime.htm

Comment: I used a while with a lot of testing to find the right setup, but it eventually worked. Thanks @JonBecher :)

Comment: You got it all wrong. Ypu must have killed the cpu with that script.AdlibRegister is not to be called in a loop, but at the start of your script. I am not sure if you want to check the time once every 250ms?

Comment: If it's going to run the script every five minutes, it needs to. Also my cpu is just fine. It only checks once a second.

Comment: @EpicKnarvik97 @Milos is right in that you don't want to have `AdLibRegister` in a while loop, as a best practice, you'd want to set exactly how much time in ms in the second parameter of the function and let it call itself, but as you said, it works just fine. Just a tip :)

Comment: @JonBecher I just want to know if you really realize what I am trying to do here. At certain times of a day, certain functions needs to be executed once. It need to be based on what the clock is. It can't be executed at a delay after the program starts. Some will work and some won't. I'll add the new script.

Comment: @EpicKnarvik97 My comment was for the old code you had up that you hadn't edited it yet, and it is your code, I only added a suggestion as to a best practice with that particular code. If you have figured it out, please post the answer to your own asked question.

Comment: Again, you are using it wrong. Take a look at the help file to see what AdlibRegister does.
Your code is wrong.
Replace AdlibRegister("Checktime", 1000) with Checktime()
And add a Sleep(1000) to the loop.
Cheers

Comment: @Milos When I tried your suggestion, it broke the script.

Comment: While 1
    Checktime()
    Sleep(1000)
    If $Server = "Running" And ProcessWaitClose($pid) = 1 Then Exit
WEnd

Comment: @Milos As I said, it breaks the script. Nothing happens if I do that.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace

```
If $time = "20:15:00" Then Say()
```

with

```
If Time() = "20:15:00" Then Say()
```

Cheers